# Passing array to file()?

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have a directory containing a changeable number of files, each of which contains a single character on the first line, and CSV for the remaining file content, such as:

```
 U
 Status4,jwalker,Tech Manual 03264
 Status3,jwalker,Status Report 3213
 Status4,rmartino,Tech Manual 52002
 ...
```

Using this code, I can easily get a listing of the all report filenames in a directory:

```
 <?php
 // Open session
 session_start();

 // Get array of reports from directory
 $files = scandir('reports');
 $files <= array_pop($files);
 $files <= array_shift($files);
 $files <= array_shift($files);

 // Extract summaries
 for ($i=0; $i <= count($files)-1; $i++) {
   $summaries[$i] = file($files[$i]);
   }
 ?>
```

The reason I would like to use the file() function in line 13 is because it would conveniently break the file into an array so I could easily reference a particular line, such as $summaries[3][2] to get the third line from the fourth file in the directory (remembering that I'm counting from the PHP default 0 here).  The PHP.net documentation doesn't indicate anything about NOT using an array as the string to be passed to file(), so I would assume there is a way to do it.  But I've only found constants and strings, not arrays being passed.

Anyone have any insight here?  Much thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing `$files <= array_pop($files);` and `$files <= array_shift($files);`? Do you even know what that does?

Comment: *"PHP.net documentation doesn't indicate anything about NOT using an array as the string to be passed to file()"* An array is not a string. The documentation explicitly states it takes a string, not an array. These two aren't equivalent. There's no such thing as an "array as string." (and a serialized array isn't a real array).

Comment: you're NOT using an array in your file() call. you're using an ELEMENT of an array which happens to be a string representing a filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no issue with passing the value of an array element `$arr[$k]` to `file()` as long as it's a string that represents a file path.

The problem is you're scanning the `reports` folder, and getting a list of file names not file paths. You need to prepend `reports` to the file name. Not doing so should cause an exception when `file()` can't find the file.

```
 <?php
 // Open session
 session_start();

 // Get array of reports from directory
 $files = scandir('reports');

 // Extract summaries
 for ($i=0; $i <= count($files)-1; $i++) {
   if ($files[$i] == '.' || $files[$i] == '..') continue;
   $summaries[$i] = file('reports' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $files[$i]);
 }
 ?>
```

Also, not sure what the following is meant to be doing, but what it's actually doing is removing the last file, I've omitted it in my answer

```
$files <= array_pop($files);
```

The following two lines are presumably removing `.` and `..` paths, I've replaced those with a check in the loop.

```
$files <= array_shift($files);
$files <= array_shift($files);
```

Comment: You're correct about the array_pop() and array_shift()--those were a convenient way to get the directory listing into an array that could be repurposed in other parts of a modular script.  The initial array_pop() was to account for a subdirectory that needed to be removed from the resultant list as well as the paths.

I see now my error with passing the filename without the relative path. And Marc B answered my other question about an element of an array being treated as a string.

Much thanks for the help, all!

Comment: A single array element value will be of whatever data type it is, be that a string, array, boolean, integer, whatever. In this case it happens to be a string, but no matter what the type, if it's in an array you access its value the same way `$array[$key]`.

Comment: Gotcha.  Again, much thanks for the help.  And for being a little nicer to those of us trying to learn.  :-)

Comment: No worries, we all started somewhere. edit [nm, you already did]:)